# Выравнивание таблицы, HTML

Tags: html, table

Есть таблица, на предпоследней строке 3 ячейки, на последней 2: [фото](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HM6G.png).
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать выравнивание последней строки по центру, но чтобы все формочки остались в левой части каждой из двух ячеек?

```html
<table cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- таких 3 -->
      <td colspan=2>
        <form name="${dayName}" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
          <center><label><h4>${dayName}</h4></label></center>
          <br><label>Date <input type="date" name="date" required readonly value="${date}"></label>
          <br><label>Time <input type="time" name="time" required value="${time}"</label>
          <br><label>Subject
                <br><input type="text" name="subject" size="53" required value="${subject}">
            </label>
          <br><label>Message
                <br><textarea rows="12" cols="55" name="message" required>${text}</textarea>
            </label>
          <br>
          <center>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
            <br><br>
          </center>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- таких 2 -->
      <td colspan=3>
        <form name="${dayName}" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
          <center><label><h4>${dayName}</h4></label></center>
          <br><label>Date <input type="date" name="date" required readonly value="${date}"></label>
          <br><label>Time <input type="time" name="time" required value="${time}"</label>
          <br><label>Subject
                <br><input type="text" name="subject" size="53" required value="${subject}">
            </label>
          <br><label>Message
                <br><textarea rows="12" cols="55" name="message" required>${text}</textarea>
            </label>
          <br>
          <center>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
            <br><br>
          </center>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Возможно, я немного непонятно объяснил. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы все было симметрично в таблице. Может быть у Вас есть идеи, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

А не легче через flexbox или display: inline-block, если нужна поддержка в IE? Просто таблицы - устаревшая и совершенно неподдающаяся адаптации на мобильных устройствах технология.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.